# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: security, object-model

Below code throw an exception at "`Item.Update();`"

```
    private void AddEmail()
    {
        site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        web = site.RootWeb;

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (site = SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                using (web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SPList list = web.Lists["Newsletter"];
                        SPListItem Item = list.Items.Add();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        Item["Title"] = txtEmail.Text;
                        Item.Update();
                        SendEmail();

                        txtEmail.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ltrMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone help me get over this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When running inside `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, do not use `SPContext.Current`. Instead create a new SPSite object, passing in `SPContext.Current.Site.Url`.

Comment: Also 'using' would release dispose SPContext,Current.Site !

Comment: 99% of the time, `RunwithElevatedPrivileges` is unnecessary, just instantiate `SPSite` with `SPUserToken.SystemAccount` as the second parameter.